# How to implement a click function for an element within a tiled grid that when clicked it & elements in it's proximity fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a fairly simple grid game where users have to click tiles to reveal content underneath. The first issue i'm struggling with is implementing a click function that would remove not only the tile clicked but also a few tiles around it, preferably random.

My current code:

```
        $('.layer img').click(function() {
            $(this).css ('display', 'none');
        });
```

Any help extending my simple code much appreciated.

Comment: CSS Transitions for fading out... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: you want any specific tiles around image to fadeout or hide, are you trying something to similar to minesweeper game in windows?

Comment: more similar to minesweeper but as i said a random selection surrounding the clicked tile.

Comment: yes i think then nelson answer is what you need i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the siblings and randomly hide some of them, like so:

```
$('.layer img').click(function() {
     sib = $(this).siblings();
     rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*sib.length)+1);
     for (i=0;i<rand;i++) {
        sib.eq(i).css ('display', 'none');
     }
     $(this).css ('display', 'none');
});
```

I'm adding here enhanced version, as OP commented, to randomly select previous or next siblings, up to 5 five of them in total:

```
$('.layer img').click(function() {
         sib = $(this).siblings();
         rand = Math.floor((Math.random()*sib.length)+1);
         rand = Math.min(5,rand);
         aprev = $(this);
         anext = $(this);
         for (i=0;i<rand;i++) {
            if (Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1) == 1 ) { //random go prev or next
               if (aprev.prev().length) {
                  aprev = aprev.prev();
                  aprev.css ('display', 'none');
               } else {
                  anext = anext.next();
                  anext.css ('display', 'none');
               }
            } else {
               if (anext.next().length) {
                  anext = anext.next();
                  anext.css ('display', 'none');
               } else {
                  aprev = aprev.prev();
                  aprev.css ('display', 'none');
               }
            }
         }
         $(this).css ('display', 'none');
    });
```

the code grew a bit because we have to control whether there are no more previous or next siblings, and in that case revert to the other.

Comment: $sib.eq(i).css ('display', 'none');
this line seems to throw up a Reference error in Chrome debugger.

Comment: I fixed that some minutes ago, I just noticed after sending my answer, just remove the $ sign, like the updated code in my answer.

Comment: thanks, i worked it out. Can this be modified so the maximum number of tiles is 5 and it's only tiles close to the one clicked ?

Comment: I've enhanced the function for those two requirements, I have not tested it but it should do the right thing.

Comment: that is fantastic, thanks if you have two seconds any comments to explain the logic would be really useful.

Answer (score 2):

If what you really need is something entirely more complex and with more control take a look at this example (pure javascript)

http://jsfiddle.net/FgQQg/1/